# How to sort and rank a vector in C++ (without using C++11)

Tags: c++, sorting, indexing, rank, c++03

I am trying to construct a function take takes a vector, ranks it, sorts it and outputs the sorted and ranked vector with the original positioning of the values. For example:  Input: [10,332,42,0.9,0] Output: [3, 5, 4, 2, 1]

I used this stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473/how-does-one-rank-an-array-sort-by-value-with-a-twist) (specifically Marius' answer) as a reference guide, however I am stuck with my code now and do not understand where the issue is.
I am running a C++03.

One of the errors I get is

`error: invalid types ‘const float*[float]’ for array subscript’ for array subscript` on my `if` statement.

```
//Rank the values in a vector
std::vector<float> rankSort(const float *v_temp, size_t size)
{
    vector <float> v_sort;
    //create a new array with increasing values from 0 to n-1
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        v_sort.push_back(i);
    }
    bool swapped = false;
    do
    {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(v_temp[v_sort[i]] > v_temp[v_sort[i+1]]) //error line
            {
                float temp = v_sort[i];
                v_sort[i] = v_sort[i+1];
                v_sort[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while(swapped);
    return v_sort;
}

std::vector<float> rankSort(const std::vector<float> &v_temp)
{
    return rankSort(&v_temp[0], v_temp.size());
}
```

Comment: On which *line* do you get the error? Please indicate it with e.g. a comment.

Comment: Also, why are you passing a pointer to the sorting function? Why not sort it in the function taking the vector?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude done

Comment: Lastly, you have an off-by-one error in the inner sorting loop. When `i == size - 1` what element in `v_sort` will be indexed by `i + 1`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's how I overflow some of my other functions, so I have adopted the same method here. I understand that for this specific example it is not necessary.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Why C++03? Most likely there is a more recent version that you can use. Eg Visual Studio first offered C++11 features in the 2010 version and C++14 in 2012. The compiler itself is freely downloadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a misconception on rankings. Array indices are of `size_t` not `float`, so you'll need to return a `vector<size_t>` not a `vector<float>`.

That said your sort is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*. If you're willing to use more memory we can get that time down to *O(n log(n))*:

```
vector<size_t> rankSort(const float* v_temp, const size_t size) {
    vector<pair<float, size_t> > v_sort(size);

    for (size_t i = 0U; i < size; ++i) {
        v_sort[i] = make_pair(v_temp[i], i);
    }

    sort(v_sort.begin(), v_sort.end());

    pair<double, size_t> rank;
    vector<size_t> result(size);

    for (size_t i = 0U; i < size; ++i) {
        if (v_sort[i].first != rank.first) {
            rank = make_pair(v_sort[i].first, i);
        }
        result[v_sort[i].second] = rank.second;
    }
    return result;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/kPD0Ln)

**EDIT:**

Yeah this actually gets a little simpler when taking a `vector<float>` instead of a `float[]`:

```
vector<size_t> rankSort(const vector<float>& v_temp) {
    vector<pair<float, size_t> > v_sort(v_temp.size());

    for (size_t i = 0U; i < v_sort.size(); ++i) {
        v_sort[i] = make_pair(v_temp[i], i);
    }

    sort(v_sort.begin(), v_sort.end());

    pair<double, size_t> rank;
    vector<size_t> result(v_temp.size());

    for (size_t i = 0U; i < v_sort.size(); ++i) {
        if (v_sort[i].first != rank.first) {
            rank = make_pair(v_sort[i].first, i);
        }
        result[v_sort[i].second] = rank.second;
    }
    return result;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/abP5VQ)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to input a vector however and not an array (albeit it's most likely not giving this impression in my code).
I tested your code and it works perfectly for arrays. Would you let me know if / how it can work for a vector input?

Comment: @Newskooler Cool, I've added code either way. If you're new to `vector`s you'll want to take them by const reference, as in my example.

Comment: I'm quite new to C++ in general, so I am reading through both your examples now. Thanks!

Comment: @Newskooler So, I got your code working: http://ideone.com/IP9ALW but I realized that it outputs something simpler than mine is outputting. Yours is printing the mapping of the sorted array to `v_temp`. Mine is printing the ranking of each element in the array. If you want the mapping that's a little simpler, you can get that like this: http://ideone.com/abP5VQ Is that what you were looking for? Should I put the mapping code in my answer instead?

Answer (score 1):

`v_sort[i]` is a `float` (it's just an element of `v_sort` vector) while only integral types can be used as array subscripts.

Probably you meant `v_sort` as an array of indices, thus, you should declare it as `std::vector<size_t>` or `std::vector<int>` something like that.

**UP:** Also, given that you change the values of the array passed, it's not an elegant way of pass it by `const` reference.

To sum up, the following code compiles correctly on my machine:

```
std::vector<unsigned> rankSort(float *v_temp, size_t size)
{
    vector <unsigned> v_sort;
    //create a new array with increasing values from 0 to n-1
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        v_sort.push_back(i);
    }
    bool swapped = false;
    do
    {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(v_temp[v_sort[i]] > v_temp[v_sort[i+1]]) //error line
            {
                unsigned temp = v_sort[i];
                v_sort[i] = v_sort[i+1];
                v_sort[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while(swapped);
    return v_sort;
}

std::vector<unsigned> rankSort(std::vector<float> &v_temp)
{
    return rankSort(&v_temp[0], v_temp.size());
}
```

Comment: The original example is with an array, so I am trying to integrate it for vectors.

Comment: Anyway, if you plan to store indices in `v_sort`, it should be a container of integer values. Vector or array index 0.5 doesn't make sense.

Comment: okay, so I can change the type of `v_sort` to `int` instead of `float`, however the error still persists.

Comment: @Newskooler And the return type of both functions also, as you just return `v_sort`

Comment: You are correct: One final bit, when I call the function, by inputting only a `vector <float>` value, I get the following error: `error: no matching function for call to ‘rankSort(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’`

Comment: If swap happens, it should loop forever. Also, your main loop compares last element to v_temp[v_sort[size]]... I don't know how your code works for non-sorted vectors.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin You right, I meant compiles correctly. Updated the answer

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I tested the code and for me it keeps looping. If I input the following vector:  `[30,0,3,302,-50]` it just goes in a forever loop.

Comment: Yes, @AlexanderAnikin has already fixed some issues. If looping of his code continues, consider using debugger tool, it's really good in dealing with this sort of problems

Answer (score 1):

```
//Rank the values in a vector
std::vector<size_t> rankSort(const std::vector<float> &v_temp)
{
    vector <size_t> v_sort;
    //create a new array with increasing values from 0 to size-1
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v_temp.size(); i++)
        v_sort.push_back(i);

    bool swapped = false;
    do
    {
        swapped = false; //it's important to reset swapped
        for(size_t i = 0; i < v_temp.size()-1; i++) // size-2 should be the last, since it is compared to next element (size-1)
            if(v_temp[v_sort[i]] > v_temp[v_sort[i+1]]) 
            {
                size_t temp = v_sort[i]; // we swap indexing array elements, not original array elements
                v_sort[i] = v_sort[i+1];
                v_sort[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
    }
    while(swapped);

    return v_sort;
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and for a vector of input `[30,0,3,302,-50]` I get the following output `[4,1,2,0,3]`, but I should be getting `[3,1,2,4,0]`

Comment: Wnaser [4,1,2,0,3] corresponds to [-50, 0, 3, 30, 302], your desired output corresponds to [302, 0, 3, -50, 30]. Are you sure you should get [3,1,2,4,0]?

Comment: Yes, I tested it a few times and I am trying to find out why this happens. If it helps, here is my code for the input vector: `vector <float> testing;
     testing.push_back(30);
     testing.push_back(0);
     testing.push_back(3);
     testing.push_back(302);
     testing.push_back(-50);` calling the function `vector<size_t> ranked = rankSort(testing);`

Comment: @Newskooler - Alexander Anikin's example produces a vector of indices sorted according to v_temp. To convert to a rank, create a vector v_rank, and use for(i = 0; i < v_temp.size; i++) /  v_rank[v_sort[i]] = i; . This will convert v_sort of [4,1,2,0,3] to v_rank[3,1,2 ,4,0].

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you adopt a more robust solution by taking advantage of what you have in the STL. To do so, we will first make an "index vector", ie. a `std::vector<std::size_t> v`such that for any `i`, `v[i] == i` is true:

```
// I'm sure there's a more elegant solution to generate this vector
// But this will do
std::vector<std::size_t> make_index_vector(std::size_t n) {
    std::vector<std::size_t> result(n, 0);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        result[i] = i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now all we have to do is to sort this vector according to a specific comparison function that will use the input vector. Furthermore, to allow for the most generic approach we will give the user the opportunity to use any comparison functor:

```
template <typename T, typename A, typename Cmp>
struct idx_compare {
    std::vector<T, A> const& v;
    Cmp& cmp;
    idx_compare(std::vector<T, A> const& vec, Cmp& comp) : v(vec), cmp(comp) {}

    bool operator()(std::size_t i, std::size_t j) {
        return cmp(v[i], v[j]);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename A, typename Cmp>
std::vector<std::size_t> sorted_index_vector(std::vector<T, A> const& vec, Cmp comp) {
    std::vector<std::size_t> index = make_index_vector(vec.size());
    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(),
        idx_compare<T, A, Cmp>(vec, comp));

    return index;
}
```

In the sorted index vector, `index[0]` is the index of the lowest value in the input vector, `index[1]` the second lowest and so on. Therefore, we need one additional step to get the rank vector from this one:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> get_rank_vector(std::vector<std::size_t> const& index) {
    std::vector<std::size_t> rank(index.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < index.size(); ++i) {
        // We add 1 since you want your rank to start at 1 instead of 0
        // Just remove it if you want 0-based ranks
        rank[index[i]] = i + 1;
    }
    return rank;
}
```

Now we combine all the pieces together:

```
template <typename T, typename A, typename Cmp>
std::vector<std::size_t> make_rank_vector(
    std::vector<T, A> const& vec, Cmp comp) {
    return get_rank_vector(sorted_index_vector(vec, comp));
}

// I had to stop using default template parameters since early gcc version did not support it (4.3.6)
// So I simply made another overload to handle the basic usage.
template <typename T, typename A>
std::vector<std::size_t> make_rank_vector(
    std::vector<T, A> const& vec) {
    return make_rank_vector(vec, std::less<T>());
}
```

Result with [10, 332, 42, 0.9, 0]: [3, 5, 4, 2, 1].
You can find a <kbd>[Live Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GszUCFTJpsg9yQON)</kbd> on gcc 4.3.6 to explicit this behavior.

Comment: Ummm... He said he already knew how to do it in C++11 he was trying to find a C++03 solution. Which this is not.

Comment: @JonathanMee then just replacing the lambda with a custom functor and removing the `auto`s will do

Comment: If it's that simple why not correct your code so it answers the question? Personally I don't think it's that simple because you have a capturing lambda.

Comment: @JonathanMee Just did

Comment: So another question here, why are you using `template <typename T, typename A>` Why pass the allocator? I don't see you doing anything with it.

Comment: @JonathanMee It is just to keep it the most generic I can. The functions will work if the user feeds it a vector using custom allocators

Comment: Nice solution. You could probably streamline that a lot, but it does what I would have done with a lambda if I'd had C++11, which I like.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my codes using STL to achieve this in a concise way to get the rank.

```
template <typename T>
vector<size_t> calRank(const vector<T> & var) {
    vector<size_t> result(var.size(),0);
    //sorted index
    vector<size_t> indx(var.size());
    iota(indx.begin(),indx.end(),0);
    sort(indx.begin(),indx.end(),[&var](int i1, int i2){return var[i1]<var[i2];});
    //return ranking
    for(size_t iter=0;iter<var.size();++iter){
        result[indx[iter]]=iter+1;
    }
    return result;
}
```