# Rank values in Vector against order preserving duplication - C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a vector, something like this :

```
[11,12,0,0,12,4,3,3,4]
```

and I want to rank it so its something like this :

```
[3,4,0,0,4,2,1,1,2]
```

If someone could provide some outlook on how this might be possible, it would be quite helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays instead of vectors. `int xarray[] = {}`. The steps to make this possible would include:

Create a temp array [without the duplicates](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2015/06/cc-program-to-remove-duplicate-elements.html)

[Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473/how-does-one-rank-an-array-sort-by-value-with-a-twist) the temp array

[Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_array_of_pointers.htm) the temp array to a new array of equal size where each value represents the index of the temp array

[Loop through the original array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234898/correct-way-of-loop-through-the-c-arrays) and update each value to equal the result from the pointer array using an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909784/how-do-i-find-a-particular-value-in-an-array-and-return-its-index) based off said value.